# How can I detect device orientation going back and forth through tabs and views?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, orientation, accelerometer

My application goes back and forth between Portrait and Landscape.  I have all of my content(labels, uiimageviews, uilabels) lined up to relocate for both orientations.  However, the only change when the device is actually rotated.  When I cycle between tabs after it has been rotated it just shows up autosized and not the way I have it setup when the user rotates it.

How can I detect the orientation of the device and display the view to reflect the orientation when the taps different tabs?

Ok, I set it to viewWillAppear.  Is there a reason why it isn't detecting the orientation and displaying the content where I have set it?

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

 UIInterfaceOrientation toOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"move buttons" context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
 [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
 if(toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
    || toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
 {
  aboutContent.frame = CGRectMake(20, 100, 280, 107);
  myLogo.frame = CGRectMake(-5, 20, 330, 65);
  bulletOne.frame = CGRectMake(40, 220, 240, 45);
  bulletTwo.frame = CGRectMake(40, 270, 240, 45);
 }
 else
 {
  aboutContent.frame = CGRectMake(40, 80, 400, 70);
  myLogo.frame = CGRectMake(230, 30, 20, 20);
  bulletOne.frame = CGRectMake(90, 140, 330, 65);
  bulletTwo.frame = CGRectMake(90, 170, 330, 65);
 } 
 [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each UIViewController's viewWillAppear check the device's orientation and if the orientation is different from how you have it layed out then send [willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:) to self.  That's assuming that your willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: will update the layout to the specified orientation.

Comment: I have never used viewWillAppear...Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: viewWillAppear gets invoked every time that VC is about to be displayed, while viewDidLoad only gets invoked once when the VC is created (loaded from NIB).  So as you switch tabs or return to a view after another VC was on screen, in fact every time before the VC comes on screen it will get a viewWillAppear message.